# C#: Selecting currently active file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-in

So I'm trying to create an add-in for Visual Studio 2012 and I'm stuck. So here's where I'm stuck.

Let's say in Visual Studio I'm working on a file. Assume it's called Default.aspx . My add-in works like this: When you press the button on the toolbar, it will copy everything on the file to a string variable and do some stuff with it.

So which function can I use to "select" the current open file? I could have 4-5 tabs open in visual studio but I only want to select the file which is currently being worked on which would be Default.aspx in this context. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a reference to the IDE first.

```
DTE2 IDE = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE)));
```

From the DTE2 reference you can access the **Active Document**

```
Document activeDoc = IDE.ActiveDocument;
```

To get the text from a document object you need the following:

```
// Get a reference to the text document
TextDocument textDoc = activeDoc.Object("TextDocument");

// Create a reference point at the start of the document.
EnvDTE.EditPoint startPoint = textDoc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint;

// Get all the text from our starting point to the end of the document.
string allText = startPoint.GetText(textDoc.EndPoint);
```

See this [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.dte2.aspx) for more details on the DTE2 interface.